# How to change the SSAS Multidimensional Cube partition location on disk?

Tags: sql-server-2014, partitioning, ssas

I have a SSAS Multidimensional Cube. There is a measure group with multiple partitions (based on year). I need to move old partitions to a different physical (slower) disk. When I create the partition I'm able to choose the physical location of it. But when partition has already been created I cannot find the place where I can change the path to physical disk. Do you know is it possible to change this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. To change the location of the particular partition in SSAS Multidimensional Cube (MeasureGroup) you have to Open SSDT->Open the Cube->Go to Partitions tab->Click on particular partition of the Measure Group->in the Properties window scroll down to the Configurable\StorageLocation-> click "..." button->in the Partition Type Selection window select "Specified folder"->click "..." and choose the new path. After this action partition needs to be reprocessed.

[image]